# NativeBase strange behaviour with Animated.ScrollView

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

Link Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ifx1orms0PHYb3LLhf5lcwrVFyjPVk1j/view

As you can see from the video, native base in this case behaves very strangely, as if it were broken.

- First problem: 
  The tabs are not fixed under the toolbar, as they
  normally should.
- Second problem:
  I am in the first "TAB1" (Info), I scroll, no problem except for the
  fact that the "TABS" should be fixed.

  I click on the "TAB2" (Movie), the elements are rendered.

  I do not even need to scroll the elements, if I click on the "TAB1"
  (Info) already, it will take the same height as the "TAB2" (Movie),
  that is the maximum height rendered.

Instead, as usual, each TAB should have its own height.

Link expo to try it: https://snack.expo.io/HJrZ9jXEf

The problem seems to be Animated.ScrollView together with the tab do not get along.

But without Animated.ScrollView I can not do the scroll effect.

How can I solve?